# unpin a parseObject with objectId

Tags: android, parse-platform

am trying to unpin an object using the object's Id

```
  ParseQuery deleteQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("TestNotes");
        deleteQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId",oId);
        deleteQuery.fromLocalDatastore();
        deleteQuery.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {



              // but inside this codes are not executing
                   Toast.makeText(context," object found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                object.unpinInBackground();


            }
            @Override
            public void done(Object o, Throwable throwable) {

           // instead they are executing here 
            }
        });
```

as you can see am not able to handle the retrieved object because the cursor is never going inside the `public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e)` method (never executing this method)

any clue why its happening do me codes are not correct as they supposed to be ???

Comment: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: brother thanks for responding i already heard about this , and it'll going to happen after 11 months i guess so

Comment: Why do you have two `done` methods in your callback?

Comment: its automatically implemented by parse api , do i need to remove one ?